No sound in 24.10 with Kernel 6.12
I just bought Lenovo X1 gen 13, with ubuntu 24.10 + kernel 6.12 everything is ok expect sound. It displays Dummy Output.
inxi -Fxxz : 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Lunar Lake-M HD Audio vendor: Lenovo
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-lnl bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a828
  API: ALSA v: k6.12.1-061201-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.2.4 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active
  Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: off (using pipewire-pulse)


# No sound card found
sudo aplay -l
aplay: device_list:279: aucune carte son n'a été trouvée...  

/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

...

options snd-hda-intel model=auto

Many thanks for yor help

I was in the same position...
...The only working solution was to cut down pipewire and go back to pulseaudio.
sudo apt install pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
systemctl --user stop pipewire.socket pipewire-pulse.socket
systemctl --user disable pipewire.socket pipewire-pulse.socket
systemctl --user mask pipewire.socket pipewire-pulse.socket
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket

On my Lenovo (Thinkpad E-14) it fixed the problems instand.
FYI: There are patches rolled out in KDE neon to fix some Intel-Audio <-> pipewire - problems. I didn't test them as i also need my notebook to work as DJ.

Hello, it doesn't work. Bluetooth doesn't anymore. I rollback to pipewire
